# Task timed out when creating DataSync agent through boto3 in aws lambda

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, boto3, aws-datasync

I'm trying to create a DataSync agent. When I use the console with the same parameters, it works fine and very quickly (a few seconds). However, if I want to create it by using the lambda function, the script returns a Task Timed Out Error of 900 seconds. (I increased the time limit to 15 mins since it gave the same error with lesser duration). I set Memory to 10240 MB. The lambda function is connected to the same VPC, and subnet, and has the same security group as the EC2 instance. Is there a way to create a data sync agent in the lambda function? I cannot believe that it lasts more than 15 minutes!

The error is as such:

```
Task timed out after 900.10 seconds
```

Code snippet:

```
def lambda_handler(event, _):
   agent_arn = client.create_agent(ActivationKey=event['activation_key'],
                                    VpcEndpointId=event['vpc_endpoint_id'], 
                                    SubnetArns=[event['subnet_arn']], 
                                    SecurityGroupArns=[event'sg_arn']])

    return {
        'agent_arn': agent_arn
    }
```

Comment: create_agent will need to call the Datasync API, so make sure that your VPC provides internet access (thru a NAT gateway), or another option would be that your VPC provides specifically Datasync API access by creating a VPC endpoint of type com.amazonaws.<region>.datasync

Comment: Hi! Thanks for the comment. I didn't mentioned but my VPC provides an endpoint of type com.amazonaws.<region>.datasync.

Comment: then maybe double-check that the VPC routes are correct (are pointing to the Datasync endpoint) for the subnets where the function is connected

Comment: Thanks again! Honestly, I don't know why, but it has started to work today. No clue what was the issue. I didn't change literally anything.